# HTTP error: 429

Tags: java, jsoup, httpurlconnection

Может ли провайдер ограничивать количество соединений в секунду? - Проверил программу offline: скорость ~220 узлов/сек. (масштабируемый добрый web-паук). Но в реале, при скорости 20 узлов в сек. `HTTP error fetching URL. Status=429` Использую связку технологий: URL, InputStream, HttpURLConnection а также пингую неработающие ресурсы для окончательного приговора и исключения с поиска. Ошибку ловит Jsoup в конце всех проверок. Ограничение по скорости вшито в Jsoup или это провайдер?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429 - `429 Too Many Requests`

Comment: Не знаю откуда вы получили тот статус http, но тот ресурс заДОСили :)

Comment: Я сразу вас неправильно понял. Тут такая неразбериха получилась: Ресурс https: //booked.co.il/ создаёт ссылки на внутренние страницы c поддоменом. В итоге получается, что каждая ссылка как отдельный ресурс 0_o Мой паучёк пока такие глупости не знает XD

Comment: Получается, что нужно ещё и IP адрес сервера записывать... А ещё лучше - анти рейтинг серверов, которые держат кучу сайтов и не могут обработать 20 запросов в секунду.

Comment: 20 запросов в секунду на 1 сервер это много. Например, в api вк и телеграмма разрешено намного меньше запросов в секунду. У вк, насколько я помню, было не больше 3 запросов в секунду. Я когда делал парсеры, то делал большие задержки между запросами, плюс при проблемах с сетью делал повторные запросы с увеличивающейся задержкой, типа 1, 5, 15, 30, 60 минут, а дальше уже можно было кидать исключение (пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/738c850639df0db20801274e1bcd8f22453028a2/html_parsing/get_game_genres/main.py#L48)

Comment: Это ужас! Хотел собрать маленькую доменную зону, а у меня сотни строк HTTP error: 429 С такими темпами, чтоб обойти доменную зону co.il мне понадобиться столько времени, сколько пешком обходить эту маленькую страну. А то и больше... На одном сервере десятки и сотни сайтов. Если бы один сайт - я бы понял. А когда куча сайтов на одном сервере, время ожидания неоправданно.

Comment: Не думаю, что такие вещи делают через HTTP, скорее что-то более низкого уровня используется, типа TCP, пытаясь подключиться. Однако, если все же через HTTP, то попробуйте делать, например, не GET запрос, а HEAD

Comment: `Ресурс https: //booked.co.il/ создаёт ссылки на внутренние страницы c поддоменом.` сервер, думаю, один и тот же, хотя по ссылкам поддоменов ходите. Да и мб попробуйте использовать то, что поисковые роботы смотрят, например на https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps